# Hi, I am unable to go further in my workouts. I mean physically unable to go on. What should I do

Tags: exercise

My brother uses the elliptical machine.  Once he gets to 30 minutes he is unable to go any further.  He just says he is physically exhausted.  What can he do to help himself over this?

Comment: How often does he use it?

Comment: Your brother could be overweight, or lazy or is legitimately pushing themselves so hard (and harder each session) they can't go on. This is too broad to answer.

Answer (score 3):

The real question is what's going with your brother, why is unable to continue to perform, and what makes him physically exhausted.

Are his joints beat, muscles sore, dehydrated and shutting down, or is working outside of his optimal heart rate zone and over exerting himself etc.. there are so many variables to this.

From my experience most people reach the breaking point because they are over exerting them self and need to to learn to pace themselves.  The only tool I know of to insure individuals are working within their range for this type of activity and getting the most out of their workouts is a heart rate monitor (HRM).

Learning to use a HRM will allow him to learn when his body is asking for a rest, this will allow him to train just below his breaking point and allow him to build up his heart and conditioning.

If he doesn’t have one I recommend finding a quality one form your local store or online.  Consider it a necessary tool for working out, similar to having a quality pair of shoes.